# Can the landlord require the final inspection to be earlier than the end of the lease?

Tags: germany

A friend of mine cancelled his rental agreement recently. The last day of the agreement will be the end of this year, so 2023-12-31. He actually wanted to move out mid december and make an appointment for final inspection and giving the keys back in late december. Unfortunately, it didn't go as planned and it'll take the rest of december to move out.

If everything goes as planned, we'll finish moving out and cleaning up at 2023-12-30 which is still one day early. Unfortunately, the company thats responsible to do these inspections only does these on workdays. Since december 30. is a saturday it'll not happen until january 2024.

The question: **I** believe, my friend *pays* until december 31. so he gets to use the apartment until december 31., the landlord can't force him to give over the apartment any earlier. If it has to happen on a weekday, the landlord has to find a weekday *after* the expected date of moving out.

My friend however thinks he has to pay another month of rent - for january 2024 - because even though we finsh cleaning the apartment at end of december, the company doing the inspection won't do it until january.

Who's in the right?

Comment: In UK, the inspection is usually on or after the last day of tenancy. The tenant still has access until the end of the tenancy for both cleaning and messing it up. If the agreement is until 2023-12-31 and you have moved out and handed back the keys, then why would rent be payable after that date? The title doesn't match the question.

Comment: What you propose is a catch-22. If you have to pay another month's rent due to someone *else's* inability to do a final inspection, then you have another month's residency, and so on, until the inspection can be done on the last day of tenancy when you hand back the keys. It's madness.

Comment: `If the agreement is until 2023-12-31 and you have moved out and handed back the keys, then why would rent be payable after that date?` Thats the point, we can't hand back the keys before next year. We __would__ be willing to hand them back at exactly the last of this year but the landlord doesn't allow us to as the company doing the final inspection doesn't work that day.

Comment: You can put the keys in the landlord's letterbox. If they can't do an inspection, why should that be your problem? If the tenancy has ended, the landlord cannot say "I can't accept the keys". Just hand them over.

Comment: @tkausl, if the landlord doesn't accept the keys until later, that doesn't mean the keys aren't made available by the former tenant and the possession fully surrendered on 31-Dec. You obviously aren't obligated to hand your own keys back before the end of the tenancy, and it's up to the landlord to either arrange to accept the keys at the end of the tenancy, or else the lost days when they don't have the keys but the property is otherwise surrendered and vacant, are entirely the landlord's forfeit.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to agree to having the final inspection earlier. Whether that is something your friend or their landlord wants to agree on, is a separate consideration.

---

I have had the final inspection a few days before the actual move-out date, when I had already removed the vast majority of my things. We then went through the check list, agreed on a few minor repairs I had to do, and signed it. I made a few photos of the finished repairs, just in case.
After that, I just put the keys into the landlord's letterbox (also outside their working hours).

AFAIK this is quite usual if the contract of the "move in freshly renovated - hand over freshly renovated" type. The alternative then is still having the "big" inspection meeting somewhat before the hand-over date plus a quick hand-over of the keys at the end of the lease/after actually moving out.

---

Your friend could of course also post the keys to the landlord on Sat, 30th (or Sun 31st) and by that would be moved out in proper time. The risk of this is mainly on your friend though: the signed inspection sheet protects your friend from the landlord unjustly claiming they damaged the flat. So does the signed "received keys" against the landlord claiming they never handed back all keys (-> and thus should pay for replacing the locks).